# Spring WebFlux couldn't switch blocking-operation to other scheduler in the result

Tags: java, spring-boot, spring-webflux, reactor-netty

I am developing web server using annotation-based Spring WebFlux(Reactor Netty).
This server calls blocking operations(JDBC).
I tried to switch every blocking operation to 'Elastic scheduler' that Reactor provides.

```
@RestController
@RequiredArgsConstructor
@RequestMapping("/member")
public class MemberApiRestController {
  private final MemberService memberService;

  @GetMapping("/all")
  public Mono<List<String>> findAllMembers() {
      return Mono
            .fromCallable(()->memberService.findAll())
            .map(member::toString)
            .subscribeOn(Schedulers.elastic())
            .publishOn(Schedulers.elastic())
  }
}

public class MemberService {
 public List<Member> findAll() {
     log.debug("Blocking Operation...")
     //Blocking - Operation.
 }
}

log is like ... 

2019-05-16 10:26:58,227 |-LOCAL [reactor-http-nio-7] TRACE       o.s.web.server.adapter.HttpWebHandlerAdapter:  87 - [165a3273] HTTP GET "/member/all", headers={masked}
2019-05-16 10:26:58,249 |-LOCAL [elastic-20] DEBUG                       MemberService:  36 - Blocking Operation...
2019-05-16 10:27:00,277 |-LOCAL [reactor-http-nio-7] TRACE       o.s.web.server.adapter.HttpWebHandlerAdapter:  87 - [165a3273] Completed 200 OK, headers={masked}
```

Because memberService.findAll() method  is blocking-operation, I switched to Schedulers.elastic().

This method is called on the scheduler. However, final process in response  is on reactor-http-nio thread.

It seems like a blocking model(reactor-http-nio thread is blocked until elastic thread job is done.).  In my opinion, If it supports non-blocking IO threading model, when you tossed the context to other Schedulers, remaining work  is processed there.

Is it possible to switch response handler scheduler? 
If it isn't possible, I would understand why do they design like this.

Comment: Did you try to put some load on the application in order to see whether `reactor-http-nio` thread is really blocked?

Comment: I put Thead.sleep(2000L) in findAll method. It made react-http-nio thread wait until Thread.sleep method is done even though it was excuted elastic scheduler.

Comment: Run for example this `./wrk -t4 -c100 -R1000 http://localhost:8080/member/all` and tell us whether the thread `reactor-http-nio-` is blocked or it is used for other requests while the `elastic-` is blocked.

Answer (score 0):

I had made a mistake of my test code.
I used RestTemplate to make a request.
I missed that Factory object for RestTemplate instance has restriction of maximum request in concurrent. ( By default, the maximum request is 5.).
After fixed maximum request number, it worked well.